# How to find a line in a file?

Tags: shell, unix

How to find a line in given file by using shell script? 
File name is /etc/crontab.The content is here:

```
17 */1 * * * root /opt/first.sh
*/1 * * * * root /opt/second.sh
```

> `grep -q "*/1 * * * * root /opt/second.sh" /etc/crontab`

I have used above command and got **`$?`** code is 1 rather than 0.

So what's wrong?. If you have another way, let me know. thanks!

Comment: what is error you are getting?

Comment: I want to use `grep -q "*/1 * * * * root /opt/second.sh" /etc/crontab` command to judge the file which is `/etc/crontab` have '*/1 * * * * root /opt/second.sh' line or not by `$?`. But, it always is 1 rather than 0.

Answer (score 2):

- is treated as wild character in unix. Even in "*", * will do its job.

use

```
grep -q "\*/1 \* \* \* \* root /opt/second.sh" /etc/crontab ## will grep correct line and give success
```

it will correct otherwise

```
grep -q "*/1 * * * * root /opt/second.sh" /etc/crontab  ## will grep nothing and still return success code
```

Answer (score 1):

To match a literal asterisk you have to tell grep that this asterisk is literal.

For that you need to encapsulate the asterisk with `[` and `]`
It'll look like this now:

```
grep -q "[*]/1 [*] [*] [*] [*] root /opt/second.sh" /etc/crontab
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match a fixed string, the easiest thing to do is to use the `-F` option:

```
$ grep -F "*/1 * * * * root /opt/second.sh" crontab
*/1 * * * * root /opt/second.sh
```

Or, to get the exit code only, add `-q`:

```
$ grep -qF "*/1 * * * * root /opt/second.sh" crontab ; echo code=$?
code=0
```

Normally, `grep` interprets the search string as a *regular expression*.  This means that characters like `*` or `.` or `+` are active.  `-F` turns that feature off so that the search string is treated as just a plain fixed string.

#### The meaning of `*/ * * * * root /opt/second.sh`

Observe what `*/ * * * * root /opt/second.sh` matches:

```
$ echo '*/ root /opt/second.sh' | grep '*/ * * * * root /opt/second.sh'
*/ root /opt/second.sh
```

But, the following does not match:

```
$ echo '*/ * root /opt/second.sh' | grep '*/ * * * * root /opt/second.sh'
$
```

`*` is treated as zero or more of the preceding characters.  So, `* * * *` matches zero or more spaces.  It does not match stars.

`grep` treats a star at the beginning of a regex specially.  Since `*` means zero or more of the preceding character and a `*` at the beginning has no preceding character, it makes no sense.  Many programs would give an error.  `grep`, by contrast, interprets such as `*` as, in this special case, a literal star.